# Can I replace my halogen with led?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, light, bulb, transformer

So, long story short: An Halogen (MR16/GU5.3) light in my bathroom went out and I replaced it with an led light (from Wilko UK, 3 pack). I know nothing of electrics, but thought heck, I should be able to change a light bulb, right?

A couple of weeks go by and the Led goes out, too. I still had 2 bulbs in the "3pack" I bought, maybe this one was just dodgy? Replaced with new Led. 2 weeks later, same thing happens.

I'm wondering if, based on the supplied images, anyone could guide me in terms of what bulb to buy (Halogen or Led!), so I can stop wasting money buying the wrong bulbs.

First picture shows the old bulb (top of my hand) and the new led I bought (bottom).

Second picture shows the transformer.

Did I buy the wrong bulbs or is my issue somewhere else?

[image]

[image]

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/172177/39705

Comment: In this case, I am replacing halogen -> led, that link seems more related to led -> led. I understand Wilko might not be reliable, but I'm wondering if there is something wrong with my setup or more than likely bad bulbs?

Comment: It would stand to reason the dimmable electronic transformer is not compatible with  LED bulbs.

Comment: Either 2 people are having the same problem the same day, or you asked the question twice, presumably because you couldn't find your original question.  This is probably because you're using an informal "cookie based account" and you'll get a different account on every browser and device, or anytime you reset cookies.  To fix that, tie an email address to your account, and use email/password, Google or Facebook login. Then you will have a stable ID to use. You can also change your display name at will.

Comment: Be sure the LED module handles AC correctly (it needs a bridge rectifier). Reverse current can incrementally damage the diode's junction. Save that, look out for heat. Use lower wattages or increase airflow.